# Ionic 6 and Angular navigates to route which is already in history

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, navigation

I am using Ionic 6 and Angular 12 and I have couple pages in the app flow. I wen to page_4 and when I checked my DOM structure it looks like:

```
<ion-router-outlet>
    <page_1></page_1>
    <page_2></page_2>
    <page_3></page_3>
    <page_4></page_4>
</ion-router-outlet>
```

After page_4 I want to navigate to new page_2 and send some data via state object:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/page_2', { state: {dataHasChanged: true} });
```

I expected:

1. Ionic will create again new <page_2></page_2> tag into DOM bellow <page_4></page_4>
2. I can retrieve state data like I usually do:

   ```
   this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras?.state?.dataHasChanged
   ```

But result is different:

1. App back to the previous <page_2></page_2> and my DOM structure looks like:

   ```
   <ion-router-outlet>
       <page_1></page_1>
       <page_2></page_2>
   </ion-router-outlet>
   ```
2. this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras is null and cannot see my data here. But I can see state data into windows.history.state object

Can someone please explain me why this happened or at least refer me to some valuable documentation ?

Comment: I did not understand correctly, are the pages all visible at the same time or do you go from one to the other?

Comment: @Talon Ionic stack all history pages in the DOM and hide all of them except the current one. I navigate from one page to another and only the last one is visible. But when I want to navigate to new page which is already in Ionic history stack router load that page except the new one.

Answer (score 1):

If you enter a page that has already been loaded, it will not load again, or at least, not always.
You can celar or update the content of the page inside `ionViewWillEnter`.

check [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle)

add it in your page.ts

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    ...
}
```

To solve the problem of navigation extras empty you can share data with a Service like this. It's not the cleanest way but it works

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataShareService {

  private __dataDict = {};

  setData(key: string, data: any) {
    this.__dataDict[key] = data;
  }
  getData(key: string) {
    return this.__dataDict[key];
  }
```

}

Comment: I know that. I do not see anywhere in documentation that page will not be loaded twice and the whole history will be removed if you navigate to some of the page which is already in the history :). This is answer for question 1, but I still do no get it why navigation state is empty (question 2).

Comment: I searched around for a while and found nothing relevant, another way a little less clean, to do this could be using a service to exchange data.
I Update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for update. I also searched and nothings relevant. I know how to fix this problem I just do not understand why it happens. Data can be sent via url/query parameters also :)